# Read file dynamically with Python and threads

Tags: python, dynamic

I want a Python script that reads in an infinite loop a file (till stopped from keyboard or process killed).

That input file is appended dynamically from top and bottom.

The Python script should have 5 threads doing the reading of the file and removing the lines read.

I am having problems doing that: either a line from the input file is read more than once (which should not happen) or the threads don't change the file properly.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
    from time import time as timer
    from urllib2 import urlopen
    import requests
    import os

    session = requests.Session()
    rawBody = "\r\n"

    i=0

    k=0
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in open('input.txt')]

    urls = lines

    def fetch_url(url):
        global k
        try:
            print url 
            return url, None, None
        except Exception as e:
            return url, None, e

    start = timer()
    results = ThreadPool(5).imap_unordered(fetch_url, urls)
    for url, html, error in results:
        if error is None:
            #print ""
            i=i+1
            #print("%r fetched in %ss" % (url, timer() - start))
        else:
            i=i+1
            print error
            #print("error fetching %r: %s" % (url, error))
    #print("Elapsed Time: %s" % (timer() - start,))
```

Here is a real example of how I wanna use the script: the input file contains a large number of urls of image files. I want to check every url for gps data. The python script needs to run continuously, even when the input file is empty and wait for updates of the urls. The threads I need to do more urls at once so it's not time consuming one by one.

And I need a nice quality script, not a "quick and dirty" sample.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You've not shown your code and there is little we can do to help you without the code.  It would be interesting to know more about what you mean when you say "the input file is appended dynamically from top and bottom"; I can't parse that — especially not the 'append at top' part.

Comment: Anyway, using threads to read a file is strange, you might want to reconsider you solution.

Comment: my code doesn't deal with the fact that input.txt needs to be updated (appendd with new data) during the python script execution

Comment: I want to create a general script that I will adapt for more purposes.After reading the file I want to call some system command based on the data.

Comment: What truncates the file?  You can't add data at the front of a file easily, and to remove lines you have to copy the rest of the file over the start.  So, maybe the design should be: (1) One thread continuously reads URLs from the file and stuffs URLs onto a queue; (2) Multiple threads read one URL at a time off the queue (with access control to ensure that two threads don't read the same URL).  Then you can truncate the file when needed and at worst you have to rewind the file before resuming reading.  You then just have to worry about how new URLs are written safely to the file.

Comment: Could you use a FIFO?  Then you don't have to worry too much about interleaving the truncation operations.  The writing process can write lines atomically; the reading process can, with care, read the lines atomically (one or more lines at a time, splitting when necessary).

Comment: Why not have the threads process contents and use thread safe mechanisms for communication between threads to manage a queue for reading and outputting into the file.  IO should be managed by a single thread, with worker threads processing content.  Threads themselves should not manage file handles, consider that in Linux file operations are ATOMIC and you will not get the results you likely desire.

Comment: my skill in python are really low so I would appreciate an actual example. The input file can be appendend at one end only (top or bottom). But at some point I might want to remove some urls that are not relevant to process and consume time.